# Write through a pipe with fputc

Tags: c, redirect, fork, pipe

For some reason when I try to write through a pipe with fputc my program doesn't work; however, it works fine when I use the write system call.  Here is the part of my code using fputc:

```
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *toSort = fdopen(ps_fd[1], "wb");
    /* close the side of pipe I am not going to use */
    close (ps_fd[0]);
    char temp;
    char buf[1];
    while ((temp=fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    {
        buf[0] = (char)temp;
        fputs(buf, toSort);
        buf[0] = '\0';
    }
    fputs(buf, toSort);
    close(ps_fd[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `fflush(toSort)` after `fputs()`

Answer (score 0):

The question title asks about `fputc()` but the code (mis)uses `fputs()`.

Note that `fputs()` expects a null-terminated string.  It is not appropriate for binary data; it won't write a zero (or null) byte.

Additionally, you are not null terminating the string. You are not providing enough storage for the null termination. You are not closing the file correctly. You should use `int temp` since `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  The minimum changes needed to use `fputs()` are:

```
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
FILE *toSort = fdopen(ps_fd[1], "wb");
close(ps_fd[0]);
int temp;
char buf[2] = ""; // Two characters allocated; null terminated
while ((temp = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
{
    buf[0] = (char)temp;
    fputs(buf, toSort);
}
fclose(toSort);  // fclose() to flush the buffered data
```

Or, using `fputc()`:

```
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
FILE *toSort = fdopen(ps_fd[1], "wb");
close(ps_fd[0]);
int temp;
while ((temp = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    fputc(temp, toSort);
fclose(toSort);
```